# Proof Verification - Convergence of a Sequence in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f$ be an element in the Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{R})=W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$. For every $h>0$, let
$$f_h(x)=\frac{1}{h}(f(x+h)-f(x))$$
Prove that
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\left\Vert f'-f_h\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=0$$

My proof seems to be unnecessarily long and anyone who can kindly check if there are any mistakes will be appreciated!

Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the set of all smooth, compactly supported functions $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. It is well-known that $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$. So there is a sequence $(\varphi_n)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\Vert \varphi_n-f\right\Vert_{H^1(\mathbb{R})}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\left\Vert \varphi_n-f\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}+\left\Vert \varphi_n'-f'\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\right)=0$$
It follows that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\Vert \varphi_n-f\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\Vert \varphi_n'-f'\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=0$$
So both $\varphi_n$ and $(\varphi_n')$ are convergent, hence Cauchy, in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$i,j>N_1\Rightarrow\left\Vert \varphi_i'-\varphi_j'\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\epsilon$$
For every $h>0$ and every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define the function
$$\varphi_{h,n}(x)=\frac{1}{h}(\varphi_n(x+h)-\varphi_n(x))$$
Now let $n$ be fixed. By the mean value theorem, for every $x$, there exists some $y\in (x,x+h)$ such that
$$\left|\varphi_n'(x)-\varphi_{h,n}(x)\right|^2=\left|\varphi_n'(x)-\varphi_n'(y)\right|^2\leq 2\left\Vert \varphi_n\right\Vert_{C^1(\mathbb{R})}^2=M_n$$
So the sequence $(\left|\varphi_n'-\varphi_{h,n}\right|^2)_h$ is dominated by the Lebesgue integrable function $g_n=M_n\cdot\chi_{\text{support}(\varphi_n)}$ (which is a scalar multiple of a characteristic function). By the dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\varphi_n'(x)-\varphi_{h,n}(x)\right|^2dx
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\varphi_n'(x)-\varphi_{h,n}(x)\right|^2dx \\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left[\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\varphi_n'(x)-\varphi_{h,n}(x)\right|\right]^2dx \\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$
So for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left\Vert \varphi_n'-\varphi_{h,n}\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=0$$
Furthermore, when $h$ is fixed, $(\varphi_{h,n})_n$ converges to $f_h$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ because $\varphi_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, $(\varphi_{h,n})_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$i,j>N_2\Rightarrow\left\Vert \varphi_{h,i}-\varphi_{h,j}\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\epsilon$$
Finally, we know that for arbitrary $m,n,p\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\left\Vert f'-f_h\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}
\leq
\left\Vert f'-\varphi_m'\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}+
\left\Vert \varphi_m'-\varphi_n'\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}+
\left\Vert \varphi_n'-\varphi_{h,n}\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}+
\left\Vert \varphi_{h,n}-\varphi_{h,p}\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}+
\left\Vert \varphi_{h,p}-f_h\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}
$$
Fix an $\epsilon>0$.

**(i)** Choose an $m_0>N_1$ and an $n_0>\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ such that
$$\left\Vert f'-\varphi_{m_0}'\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\frac{\epsilon}{5};\qquad \left\Vert \varphi_{m_0}'-\varphi_{n_0}'\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$$

**(ii)** There exists an $h_0>0$ such that whenever $0<h<h_0$, 
$$\left\Vert \varphi_{n_0}'-\varphi_{h,n_0}\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$$

**(iii)** For any fixed $h\in (0,h_0)$, choose a $p_0>N_2$ such that
$$\left\Vert \varphi_{h,n_0}-\varphi_{h,p_0}\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\frac{\epsilon}{5};\qquad \left\Vert \varphi_{h,p_0}-f_h\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$$
We conclude that for every $h\in (0,h_0)$,
$$\left\Vert f'-f_h\right\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\epsilon$$
giving the result.